# SQL Pivot with multiple columns in SELECT

Tags: pivot

I have a table with these results as shown below.

| ID1 | TableName | ID2 | TableName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Employment | 3 | Create |
| 1 | Person | 1 | Employment |
| 1 | Provider | 3 | Create |
| 2 | Person | 2 | Employment |
| 3 | Employment | 4 | Create |
| 6 | Person | 3 | Employment |
| 8 | Provider | 4 | Create |

I am trying to figure out how to get to this, if this is even possible.

| ID1 | TableName | ID2 | TableName | ID1 | TableName | ID2 | TableName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Employment | 3 | Create | 1 | Person | 1 | Provider |
| 2 | Person | 2 | Employment |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | Employment | 4 | Create | 6 | Person | 8 | Provider |

PIVOT the results after finding a matching ID.

Long shot, thinking of ability to write this a SELECT instead of a T-SQL stored procedure. Any guidance is appreciated.

I could not get it to work in SQL Select